unlocking Locked process with synchronized package in flutter dart
Is there any mechanism/process to unlock the functions inside lock.synchronized() provided by synchronized package in flutter?
I am using a Stream subscription to listen to the async call and update my local database. However if I cancel the subscription then the synchronized function is unable to unlock and I cannot enter the method at all.
class DataSyncManager {
  DataSyncManager._privateConstructor();

  static final DataSyncManager instance = DataSyncManager._privateConstructor();
  static final _lock = Lock();
  StreamSubscription<void>? _subscription;

  Future<bool> fetchAndSaveData() async {
    log('##################OUTSIDE:${AppGlobal.isSyncing.value}');
    if (AppGlobal.isSyncing.value) {
      showToast('Sync in progress, please wait');
      return false;
    }
    bool syncSuccess = false;
    await _lock.synchronized(() async {
      log('####################INSIDE');

      if (AppGlobal.isSyncing.value) {
        // Return false or handle as needed when already syncing
        showToast('Sync in progress, please wait');
        return false;
      }
      AppGlobal.isSyncing.value = true;
      final Stream<void> syncStream = Stream<void>.fromFuture(_performSyncOperations());
      _subscription = syncStream.listen(null);

      try {
        await _subscription!.asFuture();
        syncSuccess = true;
      } catch (_) {
        syncSuccess = false;
      } finally {
        AppGlobal.isSyncing.value = false;
        _subscription?.cancel(); // Cancel subscription if needed
        _subscription = null; // Clear subscription
      }
    });
    log('Lock Status: ${_lock.locked.toString()}');
    return syncSuccess;
  }

  Future<void> _performSyncOperations() async {
    try {
      final response = await _fetchData();
      if (_subscription!.isPaused) return;

      if (response.success == true && response.data != null) {
        await saveDataIntoDB(response.data!);
      }
    } catch (e, st) {
      showToast(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<ResponseModel> _fetchData() async {
    final response = await //apiCall
    if (_subscription!.isPaused) {
      throw CancellationException();
    }
    return response;
  }

  Future<void> saveDataIntoDB(UserInfo userData) async {
    
    
  }

  void cancelSync(bool isForced) {
    AppGlobal.isSyncing.value = false;
    if (_subscription != null && !_subscription!.isPaused) {
      _subscription!.cancel();
      // _subscription = null;
      if (isForced) {
        showToast('Sync cancelled');
      }
      log('Lock Status: ${_lock.locked.toString()}');
    }
  }

  void showToast(String? message) {
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: message ?? 'ASDASD',
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    );
  }
}

class CancellationException implements Exception {}

I am expecting the _lock.synchronized() function to unlock when cancelSync function is being called.
